# allow custom modules in fuel CMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, fuelcms

Firstly; I know the documentation touches this, but I find the documentation tricky to read (as I am also just starting with CI)

I read to allow a new custom `module`; I simply need to add my module folder to the '*modules allowed*' array. The below was commented out in my `MY_fuel.php`

So, since what I read referenced to do this in my `MY_fuel.php`

```
// Uncomment if you want to control FUEL settings in the CMS. Below are a couple examples of ones you can configure
$config['settings'] = array();
$config['settings']['site_name'] = array();
if (!empty($config['modules_allowed']))
{
    $config['settings']['modules_allowed'] = array('blog' 'type' => 'multi', 'options' => array_combine($config['modules_allowed'], $config['modules_allowed']));
}
```

So, I uncommented this out; and added the '`blog`' right at the start of where the `array(` is defined -- but it did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FUEL CMS there are two types of modules: [simple](http://docs.getfuelcms.com/modules/simple) & [advanced](http://docs.getfuelcms.com/modules/advanced). The simple module is basically a data model that you can add to your site which will expose form fields in the CMS admin. The advanced module is basically a separate instance of the "fuel/application" folder where you can create controllers, models, libraries, etc. for a specific purpose. In your case, the blog is considered an advanced module. Simple modules can be enabled via the `fuel/application/config/MY_fuel_modules.php` whereas the advanced modules can be enabled in `fuel/application/config/MY_fuel.php`. In your case, you would need to add the "blog" as an allowed module like so:

```
$config['modules_allowed'] = array('blog');
```